# jaspersoft mongodb aggregation the 'cursor' option is required

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

i was using mongodb 3.4 ,i recently changed it to 4.0 .This is my  script that i used in jaspersoft studio to get data :

```
{
    runCommand: {
        aggregate : 'Unite_ORG',
        pipeline : [
            {
                $project : {

                    Miss_Attr.categorie:1,
                    Miss_Attr.texte:1
                }
            },
            { $unwind : '$Miss_Attr'}
       ]
}}
```

the probléme is i'm getting this error and i don't know how to fix it :

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: The 'cursor' option is
>   required, except for aggregate with the explain argument

Comment: Maybe this link can help you https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-33393?focusedCommentId=1810549&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1810549 it refers to a change made from 3.4 to 3.6.

Comment: Please see [this] question. It is a duplicate of this question. [this]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123855/mongodb-4-0-jrexception-the-cursor-option-is-required-except-for-aggregate-w/61339241#61339241