# MongoDB 4.0 JRException: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument

Tags: mongodb, jaspersoft-studio

I recently changed my MongoDB database version from 3.4 to 4.0 and I started getting this error:

Even though I added the cursor option: cursor :{} I get the error no result Found

```
{
    runCommand: {
        aggregate : 'Org',
        pipeline : [
            {
                $project : {

                    Miss_Attr.categorie:1,
                    Miss_Attr.texte:1
                }
            },
            { $unwind : '$Miss_Attr'}
       ]
}}
```

Error:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: The 'cursor' option is
>   required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
>       at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.fillReport(ReportController.java:550)
>       at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController.access$18(ReportController.java:525)
>       at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportController$1.run(ReportController.java:443)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63) Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: The 'cursor' option is
>   required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.VerticalFillList.prepare(VerticalFillList.java:150)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.prepare(JRFillComponentElement.java:152)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:542)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:453)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:428)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2585)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:813)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:264)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:110)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:615)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:135)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: The 'cursor' option is
>   required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
>       at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryWrapper.runCommand(MongoDbQueryWrapper.java:207)
>       at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryWrapper.processQuery(MongoDbQueryWrapper.java:115)
>       at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryWrapper.(MongoDbQueryWrapper.java:93)
>       at com.jaspersoft.mongodb.query.MongoDbQueryExecuter.createDatasource(MongoDbQueryExecuter.java:104)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1257)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:726)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.FillDatasetRun.start(FillDatasetRun.java:166)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.components.list.VerticalFillList.prepare(VerticalFillList.java:102)
>       ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

This article on JasperSoft forums fixes this:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/10886

Outlined steps (on JasperSoft Server 7.2.0)

1. Download these two JAR files:

[Mongo Java Driver](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.10.2/mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.jar)

[JS MongoDB driver](https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jaspersoft-repo/com/jaspersoft/connectors/mongodb/js-mongodb-datasource/3.10.2/js-mongodb-datasource-3.10.2.jar)

2. Remove the older variants of these files from **{jasperserver_root}\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\lib**
3. Place files from step 1 into **{jasperserver_root}\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\lib**
4. Reboot reporting server

For JasperSoft Studio, this is fixed in version 7.5.0. Also, it might be that this is fixed in JasperSoft Server 7.5.0, however, my current deployment is 7.2.0